# Azure Test and Feedback - Possible To View Previous Sessions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, testng, exploratory

I am trying to get our implementation team to use the [Azure Test and Feedback browser extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/perform-exploratory-tests?view=azure-devops).

It seems like an ok tool. However, there is one thing that is causing us issues - it seems really easy for our people to lose your sessions and notes. I believe the expected process is to pick a work item, make a session, add screens, notes etc. Create a bug etc. Stop the session. I know it is a training issue to make our team add the bug - however, it never even warns if you make a session and don't save outcome. If they hit stop session they seem to lose access to all the work they have done?

Is there any way to see a users prior session details so they can save them? Is there any way to stop you from making a session and then not doing anything with it? Is there any way to auto attach it somewhere? Can we see users previous sessions and annotations etc?

It just seems very very easy for tester to do a bunch of work and then because you haven't created the bug report it loses your data.

Maybe we are using it incorrectly - just wondered if anyone had more real-world experience so I could look at optimizing the experience of the tester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the **Session timeline** page what you want? It shows all the screenshots, videos, and notes you've captured, the work items such as bugs, tasks, and test cases you've already filed, and the work items you've explored.

[image]

Alternatively, open the **Recent exploratory sessions** list directly in the **Runs** page of Azure Test Plans or the **Test** hub in Azure DevOps Server .

[image]

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/connected-mode-exploratory-testing?view=azure-devops#end-your-testing-session).

Comment: I can see the timeline - and it shows what I expect - during a current session. However, if I hit stop session how do I see what the timeline showed for the previous sessions? If I go to Recent Exploratory sessions and then view them it shows me summary information but I cannot see attached files, notes to the session? I seem to create a bug and store them there. Which is my whole issue if I don't create a bug etc are entered notes viewable? Is there a concept of a timeline that is just user feedback and notes without attaching them to a work item? it seems easy to lose the session details?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, after investigation, I also did not find out how to view the previous sessions. I think you can give [feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbFla.png) to Test & Feedback third-party extension or.ask question [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-exploratorytesting-web&ssr=false#qna).

Comment: Thanks for looking into it - it seems a bit of an odd design decision to let you build up a stack of work and then not even warn you if you will lose it forever. Will raise some feedback.